# react-select onChange not working after change options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a component using react-select, I get the options from props,
on selct option I want to rerender the select with other options - it works, but onChange not triggered.

```
import Select from 'react-select';

onChange(option){ 
   dispatch(updateOptions());
}

render(){
  return 
    <Select
      options={this.props.options}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      value={this.state.text}
      menuIsOpen
    />
}
```

Comment: did you `bind` action at constructor?

Comment: Where does your Select component comes from ? A quick look to the documentation of the library may help us to solve the problem

Comment: Need more clarity here, What do you mean by "on select option I want to rerender the select with other options ", do you want to provide the `Select` component a new array of options? How the `updateOptions` action creator work? Does your reducer handle the case correctly? There is not enought code to make assumption here, a codesandbox may help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 3):

I was made example and it's working?
Let's try it on your code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';


export default class FixedOptions extends Component {
  state = {
    value: {},
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(value) {
    console.log(value)
    this.setState({ value: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        options={[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 3}]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On the onChange I wat to update the options, not the value.

Comment: you can anything you want as soon as onChange event triggered.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-drake-wpoqu?file=/src/App.js), I have created two components one as a `Functional Component` and the other as `Class Component`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You haven't added onChange function and that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try onClick it's working as of now.